# how to Avoid ng-repeat in <tr> for particular <td> - Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to skip the ng-repeat for particular column.

My Code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(lunches,price) in lunchTwo">
                    <td>
                      <label class="label_wraptext">{{lunches}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td_width">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label>{{price}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:190px">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <select ng-controller="Quantity">
                        <option ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = data[key]">
                          {{key}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </td> 
                  </tr>
```

I need to avoid binding the 'Select' control for all the rows.

Thanks in Advance,
Stephen.L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if you want to show the select control only for the first row, you can give a check using the `index` if it is equals ZERO, then show the select box, else not.

Please find the updated code below, check if it works for you.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(lunches,price) in lunchTwo">
                    <td>
                      <label class="label_wraptext">{{lunches}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td_width">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <label>{{price}}</label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-left:190px">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <select ng-controller="Quantity" ng-show="$index==0">
                        <option ng-repeat="key in notSorted(data)" ng-init="value = data[key]">
                          {{key}}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </td> 
                  </tr>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would suggest to use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` to completely remove it from the DOM.

Comment: yes, you can use ng-if there. But i suggest it as your question how to hide it from the tr. if the answer helps you, then its fine